# MediaWiki how to watch other pages when a page is added to a watchlist

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-templates

I have a couple of pages on my wiki. And I am able to put a few of them on my watch list. But I want it to also watch a few other pages if certain pages have been put on the watch list.

I can't find anywhere on how to do this or if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [WatchArticleComplete](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/WatchArticleComplete) hook in your extension and call the [watch API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Watch) from it to insert additional pages in the watchlist.